# Array always showing the value of index in all the index values in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have array in which i insert all the values in sqlite which are different and are stored in the table but when i access the array it shows the same values for all the array indexex i have four items in the array

This how i am adding the items

```
    for (int i = 0; i<[surveyQuestions count]; i++) {

      QuestionData*data=[surveyQuestions objectAtIndex:i];



      question_text=data.question_text;
      question_type=data.question_type;

      coffeeObj.question_text =question_text;
      coffeeObj.question_type=question_type;



      NSLog(@"Inserted question %@",question_text);





       [appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];





      }



 - (void) addCoffee:(QuestionData *)coffeeObj {

    [coffeeObj addCoffee];

    [coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];

    NSLog(@"Succeessfully Added");


    }



for(int j=0;j<countmine;j++)
{
     QuestionData*data=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:j];
     NSString*myTest=data.question_text;
     NSLog(myTest);
     QuestionData*dataset=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:0];
     questionTextLabel.text=dataset.question_text;
}
```

In data base i am adding the array but it always showing the last enterend values in each index in the data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used index 0 while assigning the value to questionTextLabel. You should have use "j" here.

```
//In your answer its 0 here
 QuestionData*dataset=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:j];     

 questionTextLabel.text=dataset.question_text;
```

Comment: Same thing it always shows the value of the index 1 i think when i insert data in loop i think it takes always last value

Comment: sorrry no in NSLog it also prints the same index 2 for all the values

Comment: it should print differrent values but it prints same values for all

Comment: that means the array is either not stored correctly or not retrieved correctly.

Comment: i get the values from another array and then store in this array any idea how to fix this issue

Comment: i have also added the in which i add the values in array